# Wordpress / PHP - Set div width to fit all images

Tags: php, image, wordpress, html, width

If I call posts like this, with each post containing a number of images, is there any PHP I can use to find the total width of all images in each post, then set div id="page" to the width of the greatest?

```
    <div id="page">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            </div><!-- #post-## -->
    </div>
```

It's easy enough in javascript, I'm new to PHP but suspect it's doable?
Cheers!

Comment: do you store the width of the images in the db or something?

Comment: getImageSize() might work for you. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: This seems a little backwards to me... Why don't you try constraining the images to a set size that fits within your content div? One line of css should do the trick. Also, yes, this is easy to do using js.

Answer (score 0):

php runs on the server-side, it means that when the server generate the page, It does not know the sizes of images on the page.

You can take with the function

> get_the_content()

content of the page, then use the function

> preg_match_all

to get src and width of images.

Then, if the picture has not attribute width, use getimagesize() with src parametr of images to get width.
Then calculate the size of the div id = "page", but this way will overload the server. It is better to use js on the client side.